# Error in converting Azure AutoML model to ONNX format

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, onnx, azure-ml-pipelines, azure-auto-ml, skl2onnx

I am working with **Azure AutoML** and have created a trial using different models. In the pipeline, the final step is a **PipelineWithYTransformations**.

Now, I am attempting to convert the generated .pkl model to an ONNX model, but I encounter the following error:

```
raise RuntimeError("Unable to find a shape calculator for type "
RuntimeError: Unable to find a shape calculator for type '<class 'azureml.training.tabular.models.pipeline_with_ytransformations.PipelineWithYTransformations'>'.
```

I am unsure how to handle this error and successfully convert the model to **ONNX** format.

Here are some additional details about my setup:

- The **AutoML** trial was created with the goal of training a machine
  learning model.

```
from azure.ai.ml import automl, Input
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes

dataset_name = "DataSetName"
my_training_data_input = Input(type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE, path=dataset_name)


# configure the classification job
classification_job = automl.classification(
    compute="my_compute",
    experiment_name="my_experiment",
    training_data=my_training_data_input,
    target_column_name="Label",
    primary_metric="accuracy",
    n_cross_validations=5,
    enable_model_explainability=True,
    tags={"my_custom_tag": "My custom value"}
)

# Limits are all optional
classification_job.set_limits(
    timeout_minutes=600, 
    trial_timeout_minutes=20, 
    max_trials=2,
    enable_early_termination=True,
)

# Training properties are optional
classification_job.set_training(
    blocked_training_algorithms=["logistic_regression"], 
    enable_onnx_compatible_models=True
)

# Submit automl job
returned_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    classification_job
)
```

- I have tried using the convert function from the
  **skl2onnx** library to perform the conversion.
- The error seems to be related to the specific type of model (**PipelineWithYTransformations**)
  generated by AutoML. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions
  on how to resolve this issue and successfully convert the model to ONNX format.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to get `ONNX format model` with `Azure Auto ML` from your `run object`.

```py
remote_run = experiment.submit(automl_config, show_output=False)
```

Is by using `get_output:`

```py
best_run, onnx_mdl = remote_run.get_output(return_onnx_model=True)
```

Also, you can use `OnnxConverter Class` for saving the model in onnx format.

```py
from azureml.automl.runtime.onnx_convert import OnnxConverter
onnx_fl_path = "./best_model.onnx"
OnnxConverter.save_onnx_model(onnx_mdl, onnx_fl_path)
```

For detailed steps and sample code please check this [sample notebook.](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/classification-bank-marketing-all-features/auto-ml-classification-bank-marketing-all-features.ipynb)

**For SDKv2  (Update) :**
On executing the provided script, the `onnx format` model will be generated alongside pickle model.
To get the model you can use the below code snippet:

```py
from mlflow.tracking.client import MlflowClient
from mlflow.artifacts import download_artifacts

# Initialize MLFlow client
mlflow_client = MlflowClient()

job_name = returned_job.name
mlflow_parent_run = mlflow_client.get_run(job_name)
# Get the best model's child run

best_child_run_id = mlflow_parent_run.data.tags["automl_best_child_run_id"]
print("Found best child run id: ", best_child_run_id)

best_run = mlflow_client.get_run(best_child_run_id)

print("Best child run: ")
print(best_run)
import os

# Create local folder
local_dir = "./artifact_downloads"
if not os.path.exists(local_dir):
    os.mkdir(local_dir)
    
# Download run's artifacts/outputs
local_path = download_artifacts(
    run_id=best_run.info.run_id, artifact_path="outputs", dst_path=local_dir
)
print("Artifacts downloaded in: {}".format(local_path))
print("Artifacts: {}".format(os.listdir(local_path)))
```

This will download all the artifacts including `model.onnx file`.
[image]

For more details, you can check this sample [notebook.](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/jobs/automl-standalone-jobs/automl-classification-task-bankmarketing/automl-classification-task-bankmarketing.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your script is for AzureML SDK v1. I'm creating a job by SDK v2. In this version, the job is of type automl.classification. Do have any idea about it? @rishabhm

Comment: I have provided the automl definition here to clarify my quesion. I hope it could help to be more understandable. @rishabhm

Comment: @elldora, I have updated the solution with SDKv2 approach.